# TypeScript decorator declaration that implements an interface

Tags: typescript

I've tried a few different ways to declare a decorator function in TypeScript such that the decorated class implements an interface. Something like this:

```
interface IValidatable {
    checkValidation: () => boolean;
}

function validated<T>(Class: {new():T}): {new():T & IValidatable} {
    Class.prototype.checkValidation = () => true;
    return Class as {new():T & IValidatable};
}
```

Given the above, I was hoping that I could then do something like this:

```
@validated
class Foo {

}

let f = new Foo();
let isValid = f.checkValidation();
```

but the last line is flagged as an error ("Property 'checkValidation' does not exist on type 'Foo'.").

The following *does* work in the sense that it does not generate an error:

```
let ValidatedFoo = validated(Foo);
let vf = new ValidatedFoo();
let isValid2 = vf.checkValidation();
```

Is there a way to formulate the decorator declaration such that the first usage example does not generate an error?

Comment: It would seem that this has been an open issue for a while https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you can fix it so that the decorator changes the way the compiler thinks of the `Foo` class.
Decorators work at runtime not compile time, so when you instantiate `Foo` the compiler sees `Foo`.

I can think of the following three options:

(1) Cast the instance:

```
let f = new Foo() as Foo & IValidatable;
let isValid = f.checkValidation();
```

(2) Cast the class to an intersection:

```
interface FooConstructor {
    new (): Foo & IValidatable;
}

let f = new (Foo as FooConstructor)();
let isValid = f.checkValidation();
```

(3) Use a factory function:

```
function fooFactory(): Foo & IValidatable {
    return new Foo() as Foo & IValidatable;
}

let f = fooFactory();
let isValid = f.checkValidation();
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20IValidatable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20checkValidation%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20validated%3CT%3E(Class%3A%20%7Bnew()%3AT%7D)%3A%20%7Bnew()%3AT%20%26%20IValidatable%7D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20Class.prototype.checkValidation%20%3D%20()%20%3D%3E%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Class%20as%20%7Bnew()%3AT%20%26%20IValidatable%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20FooConstructor%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20new%20()%3A%20Foo%20%26%20IValidatable%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20fooFactory()%3A%20Foo%20%26%20IValidatable%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20new%20Foo()%20as%20Foo%20%26%20IValidatable%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%40validated%0D%0Aclass%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f%20%3D%20new%20Foo()%20as%20Foo%20%26%20IValidatable%3B%0D%0Alet%20isValid%20%3D%20f.checkValidation()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f2%20%3D%20new%20(Foo%20as%20FooConstructor)()%3B%0D%0Alet%20isValid2%20%3D%20f2.checkValidation()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20f3%20%3D%20fooFactory()%3B%0D%0Alet%20isValid3%20%3D%20f3.checkValidation()%3B))

Comment: Thanks for the reply. If by "Decorators work at runtime not compile time, so when you instantiate Foo the compiler sees Foo." you are suggesting that this could never work, even in principle, I don't think that is correct. That's partly why I included the "working" example: TS can make the correct inference in similar circumstances.

Comment: I'm not saying that "this could never work", it's how things are now. It can work if the compiler would replace the definition for `Foo` with `validate(Foo)` (which is what you did with your working example). It will also work at runtime as the js code has something like this: `Foo = __decorate([validated], Foo)` (which again is the same thing, just happens only at runtime)

Comment: @DanielPratt dig deep and find a way to get typing for decorator generated methods using an interface. This is the holy grail of 1 offs.